# What does exit code 77 mean in Python?

Tags: python, exit-code

Does anyone know what does exit code 77 mean? I am using Python 3.7 with Pycharm as an IDE. Whenever I attempt to run any program, the output ends after a few seconds saying

```
Process finished with exit code 77
```

This did not happen before at any time, but started happening a few months back, and I simply ignored it, but it didn't get better with time. I think this error also happens with the prompt, as the prompt just suddenly exits after a while.

How do I fix this?

Comment: This message comes from the operating system, not from Python.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest Windows 10.

Comment: Based on a simple search, I would venture a guess that something's afoot with permissions?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel What kind of error is that then? What does it mean?

Comment: Is the error limited to Pycharm, or same thing happens when you run Python from CMD? Did you install Python with admin permissions?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I did receive an error saying: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Pycharm 2020.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\packaging_tool.py pyvenv C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Pycharm Projects\Puzzle\venv\Include\Include\Include

Comment: @OneCricketeer It also happens when I run Python from CMD, I didn't install Python with admin permissions.

Comment: Did you try putting `what is a process exit code` into a search engine? Or something similar to that?

Comment: I suggest re-installing Python 3.8 or 3.9, and make sure to right click the executable to run as admin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On all Unix operating systems, every time a process exits, it returns an exit status that tells the operating system whether the process ran successfully or encountered some sort of failure mode.

Knowing whether a tool is successful or not is important, but providing more information to the rest of the system has many advantages. Unfortunately, there are no universal standards for exit codes that go beyond the standard failure code.

The closest there is to an official extended standard comes from the BSD family of operating systems. The header file sysexits.h defines 15 new error statuses in the range of 64 to 78. These include options for returning based on both system errors and user errors. Unlike with C, sysexits.h does not declare 1 as the generic failure exit status, but instead covers most needs under the new statuses. The exit statuses provided by sysexits.h are as follows:

```
64 - Command line usage error
65 - Data format error
66 - Input is not openable
67 - Addressee unknown
68 - Unknown host name
69 - Service unavailable
70 - Internal software error
71 - System error
72 - Critical OS file missing
73 - Can no create output file
74 - I/O error
75 - Temporary failure
76 - Remote error in protocol
77 - Permission denied
78 - Configuration error
```

check this [link](https://krueger.report/programming/exit-status-codes/)

Answer (score 2):

Exit code 77 means permission denied.