# Ubutu 20.04: lando db-import data.sql error, 'No such file or directory'

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, lando

I am on `Ubuntu 20.04` and `lando 3.6.1`. I have a WordPress site setup with lando. Everything is fine except that I am unable to import the SQL dump using the following command:

```
$ lando db-import ucoh-data.sql
```

The dump is placed at the root of the lando application.

When running from a command window (CLI):

```
chown: cannot access '/app/ucoh-data.sql': No such file or directory
```

When running inside a PHPStorm terminal:

```
lando db-import ucoh-data.sql
Lando should never ever ever be run as root...
   ___ __                          ______
  / (_) /_____   ___ _  _____ ____/ / / /
 / / /  '_/ -_) / -_) |/ / -_) __/_/_/_/ 
/_/_/_/\_\\__/  \__/|___/\__/_/ (_|_|_)  
                                         

Process finished with exit code 77 at 18:21:33.
Execution time: 252 ms.
```

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/66198677/1496518 The **exit code 77** means **Permission Deined**. I cannot understand which particular area could be responsible for this permission thing!

I tried to find a solution in Google for nearly 2 hours but could not find anything really useful, especially for the version of Ubuntu Iam currently using.

**UPDATE:**
The permission for `/usr/share/lando` directory in my PC is

```
rwxr-xr-x    4 root root   4096 Nov 10 18:17 lando
```

Comment: Did you installed docker to run as `non-root`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced a similar issue with a Lando Drupal install.
I resolved it by adding the database import command directly into my .lando.yml "tooling" (per Lando Docs https://docs.lando.dev/guides/db-import.html):

```
tooling:
  'db-import <file>':
    service: :host
    description: Imports a dump file into a database service
    cmd: /helpers/sql-import.sh
    user: root
    options:
      host:
        description: The database service to use
        default: database
        alias:
          - h
      no-wipe:
        description: Do not destroy the existing database before an import
        boolean: true
```

Then I ran `lando rebuild`.
After that I was able to import my database with no errors.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, it was caused me overriding the `/app` path in the appserver container but not the database server too, so the database container couldn't find it. I used the below:

```yaml
  database:
    # required for `lando db-import to work (file must be in myfolder folder)`.
    app_mount: delegated
    overrides:
      volumes:
        - '../myfolder:/app'
```